# Apparent compilation error with template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Playing around trying to make a fraction class, found an apparent glitch. 
This code shows the problem,

The class is:

```
template <int A, int B>
struct two_ints
{
    static constexpr int first = A < 100 ? A : -1;
    static constexpr int second = B < 100 ? B : -1;
};


template <typename T>
struct myPair
{
    T one;
    T two;
    template <int A, int B>
    constexpr myPair(two_ints<A, B>)
        : one(two_ints<A,B>::first), two(two_ints<A,B>::second){    }

    template <int A, int B>
    struct make_pair
    {
        static constexpr myPair<T> value = myPair<T>(two_ints<A,B>());
    };
};
```

When I create an object of the class with "int" as the template perameter it compiles with no problems e.g.

```
int main()
{
    typedef myPair<long> int_pair;
    int_pair pairTwo(two_ints<67,45>());
    int_pair pairThree(int_pair::make_pair<67,45>::value);

    return 0;
}
```

But then i uses "long long" as the template parameter and it fails to compile.

```
int main()
{
    typedef myPair<long long int> int_pair;
    int_pair pairTwo(two_ints<67,45>());
    int_pair pairThree(int_pair::make_pair<67,45>::value); //error here

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:
    undefined reference to myPair::make_pair<67, 45>::value'
Using compiler: GNU GCC Compiler

Edit:
To complicate matters further, if i make value and constexpr function istead of variable then the code compiles...

```
static constexpr myPair<T> value() { return myPair<T>(two_ints<A,B>()); }
```

and then in `int main()`

```
int_pair pairThree( int_pair::make_pair<67,45>::value() );
```

This gives no errors at all.

Comment: that should fail anyway, since two_ints is not defined

Comment: Appologies, copy and pasting error...

Comment: I wonder if that's even legal, as `myPair<T>` is incomplete at the point where `value` is defined.

Comment: I'm not saying its good code but it compiles with int but not long long and i am perplexed as to why

Comment: `int_pair pairTwo(two_ints<67,45>());` is a function declaration

Comment: `int_pair::make_pair<67LL,45LL>` ?

Comment: Works with [g++4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecd6f663f446d0d8) and clang++3.4.

Comment: It seems to work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f9005f5d976155f).

Comment: @BbbobbB, Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit compiler? Check whether long long int data type is supported or not.

Comment: Long long is definitely supported as a template argument in my compiler i checked it and it works with a very simply struct